# Should memcached be installed before or after cpanel?

Tags: memcached

I want to install [memcached](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/NewInstallFromSource).

I want to know if I should install cpanel first, or after the memcached installation

Comment: **Questions involving web hosting control panels** are off-topic at [sf] because they [customize their systems such that normal administration tools and methods no longer apply](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/8055), and thus require support from the vendor or the web hosting industry. See [Where can I ask questions about web hosting control panels?](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/8094)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think memcached is a prerequisite for cpanel or vice versa. So, you can install it before or after. It should not matter.